# How do you make a normally terrifying premise into something funny?

Tags: fan-fiction, comedy

I came up with an idea for a Club Penguin fanfic, which is supposed to be a sort of dark comedy where sometimes puffles attack and/or kill penguins because they are animals. Obviously, getting attacked and/or killed by an animal would be horrifying, but that makes me wonder: How do you make a story that would normally be terrifying into something that's funny?

Comment: Why did you want to write this story in the first place? Why penguins? Are they a metaphor for something? People wearing black-and-white suits are often compared to penguins. Also penguins are funny because of the way they walk. A man with their pants down will walk like a penguin.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways. Maybe more but I can only think of two.

The first is the break in tension. Your characters are creeping around expecting to get attacked or bitten or whatever. But you can't keep the tension maximum for too long. It becomes boring. Oh look, another corner we have to go around without knowing what's around it.

So you stick in something surprising. If you've seen a long series of human victims, you suddenly find a kangaroo. Or there's a TV playing and the show is an old 1960s episode of one of those "scary" shows that has a monster similar to the one you have in your story. You get the idea.

This resets the tension level back to close to zero. Everybody laughs a little. Then they look around and realize they are still in the Very Bad Situation. And the tension starts to rise again. It feels like the tension has risen for much longer and to much higher levels, even though not much has changed.

Another direction of the release in tension is when somebody thinks they have defeated the monster. And it turns out they have only defeated a doofus in a monster costume. Or they think they've escaped but there's one more wall and the monster is hiding behind a post. You get the idea.

The other approach is farce. Think the various Scary Movie franchise episodes. Think the movie Dracula: Dead and Loving It. Or the movie Young Frankenstein. You accept that you are being deliberately silly. You include running gags (like, every time you pass the picture in the living room the eyes follow you). You have over-the-top characterization. Your mad scientists really is insane, with a white coat, crazy hair, crazy eyes, one of those things where sparks climb up a rod, and an assistant named Bruce. And Bruce is the only thing that stops the evil plans from working. Maybe it's even an entire family of Mad Scientists. Mom, Dad, Daughter, Son, the Twins, all in their own white coats with crazy hair, crazy eyes, and their own thing with sparks climbing up a rod. And each one has their own assistant who gets in their way and spoils their plans.

You have the characters creeping around looking for the monster. And, cartoon-like, the monster creeps up behind them and helps them peak around corners. And they keep this up, even getting the monster to hold the candle for them. Or you go get the episodes of Three Stooges or Abbott and Costello when they go to a haunted house. Or the Carry On movies where they had a haunted house.

And don't forget silly accents. Think of the fireplace scene from the movie Young Frankenstein. "Put! ... The kendle! ... Beck!"

That is, you get every cliché and fasten it on your story, and exaggerate it to the max.